# Custom name of root user

Tags: linux, user-accounts, root

Obviously, the root user's username is root. Is there a way to change it's username to something else while keeping it's root powers? Example: Change it to webadmin on a http server.

Comment: Did you see [How do you rename root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8447/how-do-you-rename-root) on Unix & Linux stackexchange.

Comment: Oh shoot, I couldn't find that, thanks. If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against it, because some software may depend on there being an account named root. But if you insist:

- Boot a live-distribution from an USB-stick.
- Mount the root filesystem.
- `usermod --root /path/to/mounted/filesystem --login newname root`.

The booting to a live-distribution is necessary because `usermod` won't let you change the username of an user that has running processes. Note that the above command doesn't change anything else besides the name. You might want to add `--home /path/to/new/home --move-home` and you should probably rename the mail spool. See `man usermod` for further information.